# how to Access Sharepoint Custom list from Xamarin

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Custom List in **sharepoint** and i need to send data from **Xamarin** to this custom list, does there any possible way?

Answer (score 0):

[Sharepoint Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390%28v=office.12%29.aspx) can manipulate [lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx)